# Month + year in range in Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know that we can set range of years in Jquery date picker as follows:

```
$("#calendarInput").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2010:2014'
        });
```

My question is: if I want the range to only allow a date between one month prior and one year greater than today's date.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: use the `mindate` and `maxDate` options.

Comment: It has to be relative to the current date. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Official Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max) you can use minDate and maxDate
in your case for one month prior to 1 year greater from now, it would be:

```
$("#calendarInput").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate:'-1M',
            maxDate:'+1Y',
});
```